# Search hashtag in instagram then filter by location

Tags: python, geolocation, instagram, hashtag

How can you search Instagram by hashtag and filter it by searching again using its location?

I checked the Instagram API, but I don't see a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If u can't find ready solution for this in api, try to search by location first.
As u receive location search results, you can manually filter them by hashtags.

The idea is that every photo has tags and location attributes you can filter by. But everything depends on your specific task here.